# Fragment shader not lerping textures correctly

Tags: fragment-shader

Im trying to blend two textures (sand and grass [ignore the grass straws]) in my game based on the height of the points. I have somewhat succeeded, but the result is a little bit odd.

In my frag function:

```
return lerp(tex2D(_SandTex, input.uv), tex2D(_GrassTex, input.uv), InverseLerp(_SandStart, _GrassStart, input.positionWS.y)) * mainLight.shadowAttenuation;
```

[image]

As you can see, it seems like every second triangle is very different, while both 'sets' of triangles are blending fine down and up through the y axis, they should be differentiate a lot with their neighbours.

What am I missing here?